# The boost io service object

Tags: c++, boost

I'm reading some documentation about asynchronous I/O, but I have some trouble understanding this:

It’s not possible to give general advice about when it makes sense to use more than one I/O service object. Because **boost::asio::io_service** represents an operating system interface, any decision depends on the particular interface.

On Windows, boost::asio::io_service is usually based on **IOCP**, on Linux, it is based on **epoll()**. Having several I/O service objects means that several I/O completion ports will be used or epoll() will be called multiple times. Whether this is better than using just one I/O completion port or one call to epoll() depends on the individual case.

Who can give me more details please?

Thanks.